# Lotus Notes Attachment

Tags: lotus-formula

I use @Command([EditInsertFileAttachment] ) in order to insert attachment file
in document. Navigator is appeared and I choose file I want.
I want in the mean time  to delete  the source file in folder so I use
@Command([EditInsertFileAttachment] ;   ; "0" ; "0" ; "1" ; "0"   );

But un message " Missing semicolons " appeared. Please advice !

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible in Formula language. The parameter "deleteexisting" is there to delete a file attachment with the same name from the document and not the source from the file system.

For this to work you need to write the complete code in LotusScript. If you need concrete help with that then write a new question about your LotusScript Code.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you read the HCL docunentation as you are using the parameters incorrectly.
There is no time parameter, I think what you want is impossible.